# raspberry pi issues while running smart mirror

Tags: python, linux

I want to install a smart mirror on a raspberry pi. I have done all initial steps, but I am getting an error while running smart mirror. the error is

No protocol specified

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "mm.py", line 329, in <module>
     w = FullscreenWindow()
   File "mm.py", line 296, in __init__
     self.tk = Tk()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1813, in __init__
     self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
 _tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0.0"
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: What you are doing requires an X session, there seems to be none.

Comment: what should i do? please suggest me.

Comment: Get a graphical session, either locally or ssh in from a system that has an open X graphical session with `ssh -X`.

Comment: I will try that thank you @klaus D

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*